# What goes in /var?

Tags: linux, command

I read [The Linux Command Line](http://linuxcommand.org/) by William Shotts, and there are some descriptions of Linux files (system directories):

> The `/var` directory contents don't change. This tree is where data that is likely to change is stored. Various databases, spool files, user mail, etc. are located here.

I am wondering: If the `/var` directory contents are not supposed to change, why is there a `www` directory in `/var/www` after installing `apache-php`?

The `/var/www` directory is where we must edit, create or delete files. This is a localhost public directory.

Why did he say, that the `/var` directory contents don't change?

Comment: "*don't change*. This tree is where data that is *likely to change*" -  the quote is self-contradictory

Comment: Is this really what it says in your book? What I can find on page 23 in "The Linux Command Line" version 17.10 by William Shotts makes more sense: "With the exception of /tmp and /home, the directories we have looked at so far remain relatively static, that is, their contents don't change. The /var directory tree is where data that is likely to change is stored. Various databases, spool files, user mail, etc. are located here."

Answer (score -24, accepted):

I'd say that the contents in /var don't change *so often*.
In my experience it's mostly used to store database files, cache files and of course, the /var/www directory.
These objects do change but for example, a website doesn't change every second.

Comment: But it also holds things like `/var/log` which, on busy systems, can be changing significantly on a sub-second time scale...

Answer (score 114):

That description of `/var` is self-contradictory. `/var` contains things that are prone to change, such as websites, temporary files (`/var/tmp`) and databases. The name is an abbreviation of "variable".

Comment: The accepted answer and this are conflicting each other. but this has more votes. can any one help!!

Comment: @Sandeep I think the accepted answer is chosen by the person who asks the question.  This person may not have had enough information before they chose an accepted answer.  Generally speaking, answers with more votes will help more people.  I suggest reading the comments below each answer, and follow any links provided by the answer's author before making your decision.  In my opinion, for this question, the accepted answer is incorrect.

Comment: Change can occur in more than one way. Variable files may change in size (footprint) or possibly quantity. Use `/var` if you have a set number of files which may be growing (i.e. due to log appending or rotation) over time so as not to run out of disk space.

Answer (score 57):

From `man hier`, which has a "description of the filesystem hierarchy:"

> `/var`   This directory contains files which may change in size, such as spool and log files.
>
> `/var/account`
> Process accounting logs (optional).
>
> `/var/adm`
> This directory is superseded by `/var/log` and should be a symbolic link to `/var/log`.
>
> `/var/backups`
> Reserved for historical reasons.
>
> `/var/cache`
> Data cached for programs.
>
> `/var/cache/fonts`
> Locally-generated fonts (optional).
>
> `/var/cache/man`
> Locally-formatted man pages (optional).
>
> `/var/cache/www`
> WWW proxy or cache data (optional).
>
> `/var/cache/<package>`
> Package specific cache data (optional).
>
> `/var/catman/cat[1-9]` or `/var/cache/man/cat[1-9]`
> These directories contain preformatted manual pages according to their man page section.  (The use of preformatted manual pages is deprecated.)
>
> `/var/crash`
> System crash dumps (optional).
>
> `/var/cron`
> Reserved for historical reasons.
>
> `/var/games`
> Variable game data (optional).
>
> `/var/lib`
> Variable state information for programs.
>
> `/var/lib/hwclock`
> State directory for hwclock (optional).
>
> `/var/lib/misc`
> Miscellaneous state data.
>
> `/var/lib/xdm`
> X display manager variable data (optional).
>
> `/var/lib/<editor>`
> Editor backup files and state (optional).
>
> `/var/lib/<name>`
> These directories must be used for all distribution packaging support.
>
> `/var/lib/<package>`
> State data for packages and subsystems (optional).
>
> `/var/lib/<pkgtool>`
> Packaging support files (optional).
>
> `/var/local`
> Variable data for /usr/local.
>
> `/var/lock`
> Lock files are placed in this directory.  The naming convention for device lock files is `LCK..<device>` where `<device>` is the device's name in the filesystem.  The format used is that of HDU UUCP lock files, that is, lock files contain a PID as a 10-byte ASCII decimal number, followed by a newline character.
>
> `/var/log`
> Miscellaneous log files.
>
> `/var/opt`
> Variable data for `/opt`.
>
> `/var/mail`
> Users' mailboxes.  Replaces `/var/spool/mail`.
>
> `/var/msgs`
> Reserved for historical reasons.
>
> `/var/preserve`
> Reserved for historical reasons.
>
> `/var/run`
> Run-time variable files, like files holding process identifiers (PIDs) and logged user information (utmp).  Files in this directory are usually cleared when the system boots.
>
> `/var/spool`
> Spooled (or queued) files for various programs.
>
> `/var/spool`
> Spooled (or queued) files for various programs.
>
> `/var/spool/at`
> Spooled jobs for `at(1)`.
>
> `/var/spool/cron`
> Spooled jobs for `cron(8)`.
>
> `/var/spool/lpd`
> Spooled files for printing (optional).
>
> `/var/spool/lpd/printer`
> Spools for a specific printer (optional).
>
> `/var/spool/mail`
> Replaced by /var/mail.
>
> `/var/spool/mqueue`
> Queued outgoing mail (optional).
>
> `/var/spool/news`
> Spool directory for news (optional).
>
> `/var/spool/rwho`
> Spooled files for `rwhod(8)` (optional).
>
> `/var/spool/smail`
> Spooled files for the `smail(1)` mail delivery program.
>
> `/var/spool/uucp`
> Spooled files for `uucp(1)` (optional).
>
> `/var/tmp`
> Like /tmp, this directory holds temporary files stored for an unspecified duration.
>
> `/var/yp`
> Database files for NIS, formerly known as the Sun Yellow Pages (YP).

Comment: Here's an online manpage: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/hier.7.html

Answer (score 17):

The definition of various files (including directories) which are expected to be available is given by the Linux [File-system Hierarchy Standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) and the [Linux Standard Base](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/lsb.shtml). The [/var hierarchy](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_2.3/fhs-2.3.html#THEVARHIERARCHY)

> contains variable data files. This includes spool directories and files, administrative and logging data, and transient and temporary files.

Interestingly `/var/www/` is not defined in such normative specifications.

Answer (score 0):

I read some description about `/var` in [linfo.org](http://www.linfo.org/var.html):

> Among the various subdirectories within /var are /var/cache (contains cached data from application programs), /var/games (contains variable data relating to games in /usr), /var/lib (contains dynamic data libraries and files), /var/lock (contains lock files created by programs to indicate that they are using a particular file or device), /var/log (contains log files), /var/run (contains PIDs and other system information that is valid until the system is booted again) and /var/spool (contains mail, news and printer queues).